# EF entity Property Set method confusing behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

While investigating a bug I discovered something odd, and did this quick demo below to confirm what I was seeing. If my DB contains a firstname of "Bob" and a lastname of "Jenkins", can someone explain to me why the calculated name returns only Bob? When stepping through, I can see that the first name setter method is called, and that the lastname is null at that point. The setter for last name is never called.  Yet, the console writes out first name and last name correctly, it's just the calculated name that doesn't seem to do what I'd expect.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new SchoolContext())
            {
                var x = db.Students.ToList();
                Console.WriteLine(x.First().FirstMidName);
                Console.WriteLine(x.First().LastName);
                Console.WriteLine(x.First().CalculatedName);
            }

        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        private string lastName;
        private string firstname;

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { 
            get {
                return lastName;
            } 
            set {
                lastName = value;
                CalculatedName = FirstMidName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }
        public string FirstMidName { 
            get { return firstname;}

            set
            {
                firstname = value;
                CalculatedName = FirstMidName + " " + LastName;
            }
 }

        [NotMapped]
        public string CalculatedName { get; set; }


    }

    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {

        public SchoolContext()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=C:\sourcode\ConsoleApp1\students.db");

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
  Bob
  Jenkins
  Bob
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that it seems to be related to the naming of the the backing field. If I rename the private fields to something different, it works as expected. Which seems to tally with this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating a fixed variable in the setters, you could use a calculated expression: public string CalculatedName => FirstName + " " + LastName;

Comment: Yes, that's how I would normally do it, this was just an interesting observation I'd noticed while trying to fix someone else's bug. I could see what was happening, I just couldn't work out why it was happening.